# What is the best way to Create a CoreData Model Desing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, core-data, database-design

**I ask only a Model not codes or how can i add them to list or what is right codes. I learned how can i add attributes to entities and fetch them. I need only how can I do Main list which will contain my all entities and attributes. When i want to show me the Favorite players in all entities it should show them all for me..**

I created a datamodel for my data based project. I should explain my project.

I want to create a **League table view** which is contain my all teams and user can add teams in this leauge tableview in **add teams viewcontroller.**

I created two Entities first entity name is **Teams**, second Entity name is **FavoritePlayer**.

My League table view should show all user added Teams in cell text and Favorite players in cell detail text How can i do that with **CoreData.** I want to learn CoreData so and don't want to do this with Arrays or Dicts.

Should I create another Entity which name is Leagues ? if Yes, How can i do this without attributes ? 
or Should I use **Parent Entity** option.

**Actually what is the right way for create a datamodel ?**

Thank you !

--------------------- UPDATED QUESTION ------------------------

First of all Thank you very much stevesliva.

I have to explain my project to you for answer me easily..

I want to make a easy user entry database. My project will contain ;

1- MainList Entity which is the main entity and first scene in my app. 
MainList Entity doesn't have any attributes. It will show all Entities properties. It's TableViewController and 1 bar button to go addList.

AddList is a tableview controller. It has 2 static Cell titles are Bills and Bank Loans.There are  2 cell segue for go to the these items AddViewControllers.

2-I created BankLoan and Bill Entity. They have attributes.String and Number.
Bankloan has bankName and loanTotal
Bill has billName and billTotal

They have AddViewControllers to add these datas to their Entities.

CoreData Model;

MainList have two to many ordered relationship with bankLoan and Bill
bankloan and bill 1 To One relationship with MainList entity and of course inverse. And I created 2 Custom NSManagedObject class from Xcode Editor menu.

MainList custom class have 2 NSOrderedSet.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOrderedSet *bills;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOrderedSet *bankLoans;
```

---

Now there are my problems ;

1-I can't Fetch managedObjectContext all Entity items. I can Fetch only empty mainList Entity. and I cant create a FetchResultsController because fetchResultsController require a sortDescriptor. I cant create sort Descriptor either because i don't have any attributes in MainList. That is the first problem.

2- If I add all properties to NSOrderedSet how can I fetch datas with SQLLite codes.exp: LIKE,[c] >== or <== codes.I cant create Fetchresultscontroller without attributes. when I want to show only bills BeginsWith "something". I cant do..

What is the best way to create this project with Core data?

What will you do in this situation ?

Thank your for your interest and all answers. You are very helpful for me.

Comment: conceivably a **singleton** could be relevant to you. if you're just getting in to engineering, work that in to your skillset to begin with, enjoy

Comment: thank your for comment. I will research singletons but can u tell me a idea can do this ? because singleton is a huge concept i cant learn it short time.

Comment: Please someone help me for do this ?

Comment: where is everyone ? what is the problem why people dont answer me?

Comment: @leonthegosu First, you are here asking for free help.  Getting impatient when people do not volunteer their time to answer your question will not garner much sympathy, and will actually cause some to simply ignore you.  Second, maybe you should edit your question so it makes more sense.  As it is written, I can't even figure out what you are asking.  Maybe I am not alone.

Comment: @JodyHagins thank you for comment. My english and programmer skills are not enough to describe myself clearly. So  next time I will pay my attention to write questions.

Comment: Can someone help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a team entity.
Create a player entity.

If you want a league entity, it would have a to-many relationship to team.  And a to-one from team to league.   League would not be a "parent" of team, because team doesn't subclass league.  You should create a league entity if you want to track leagues in core data.  If you don't want to leagues to have any attributes, then they can just have a relationship to teams, but then you wouldn't be saving any other information, like the leagues name, to the persistent store.

Create a to-many relationship from team to player.
Create a relationship from player to team.

Create attributes for the information you want associated with each entity.

That is the way to create the data model.

Then, create a subclass of UITableViewController.  Have it be the delegate and datasource for your UITableView instance. Have it implement the functions you need, which fetch from and modify the managed object context.

Alternatively, you could have the UITableViewController subclass use a singleton teamManager or playerManager or *whatever*.  Here is a blog post about singleton "managers:"
http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

I believe that answers all of your questions.

Oh. Except for the "why don't people want to answer me."

1. It is not clear what your problem is.  It's not clear whether you are *only* asking about what data model would be best, and if you are, it's not clear what you don't understand.  We need some known unknowns.
2. Stack overflow is good for answering specific questions.  It is not a place for on demand tutorials.  There are likely *dozens* of core-data-to-tableview tutorials you could find.  You are supposed to read those first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer is very useful for me. I created a datamodel with your answer. But I am wondering Can I fetch all entity attributes(like team name and player name) from League Entity ?Because I want to list them all in my main tableview controller.There is my model http://postimg.org/image/whb2y0d2z/ Thank your for your interest again...

Comment: Once you have fetched a single league entity, the players relationship is an NSSet. Nothing you would need to fetch.  It's just NSSet *playerSet = myLeague.players. But if you want to display in a table, you likely want the relation ordered.  So check "Ordered" on the to-many relation players and you'll get an NSOrderedSet for myLeague.players.   And then you can use index it by row or whatever.  You would use a fetch to do something like get all the leagues, or all the players regardless of league, or all players older than a certain age...

Comment: I couldnt make the League entity. I followed your directions and I coreData created NSOrderedSet in my Teams.h file and i wrote this code to my SaveButton method `[_addTeamToLeague.League setValue:_teamname.text forKey:@"teamName"];` and i called NSOrdered set from Teams file to my tableview with objectAtIndex. Its returned 0 index. What is wrong ? Thank you !

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking-- the code snippet is w/o enough context-- though it's expanding the scope of your original question again, which sort of sucks as you haven't even accepted my answer to your first several questions.

Comment: Alright.  To add a team to a league, you would simply get the league's teams NSOrderedSet, add a team object to that set, and assign the set to the league's teams NSOrderedSet:
NSMutableOrderedSet *teamSet = [myLeague.teams mutableCopy];
[teamSet addObject:myTeam atIndex:teamSet.count];  myLeague.teams = teamSet;